# Control Matplotlib legend box width for wrapping

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to fix the width of the legend box in Matplotlib (Python 2.7). Here is a simple example of the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5, 8.5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.0882, 0.0588, 0.8882, 0.9118])

x = np.array([0,1,2,33])
y = np.array([0.1,2,4,8])
z = np.array([0,1,3.7,7])
t = np.array([0.5,1,12,41])
v = np.array([0.9,7,24,54])
a = np.array([0.2,11,17,61])
q = np.array([0.4,17,15,80])
r = np.array([0.9,3.7,18,44])
s = np.array([0.2,10,19,31])

y1 = y+1
z1 = z+1
t1 = t+1
v1 = v+1
a1 = a+1
q1 = q+1
r1 = r+1
s1 = s+1

ax.plot(x,y,label='y')
ax.plot(x,z,label='z')
ax.plot(x,t,label='t')
ax.plot(x,v,label='v')
ax.plot(x,a,label='a')
ax.plot(x,y1,label='y1')
ax.plot(x,z1,label='z1')
ax.plot(x,t1,label='t1')
ax.plot(x,v1,label='v1')
ax.plot(x,a1,label='a1')
ax.plot(x,q1,label='q1')
ax.plot(x,r1,label='r1')
ax.plot(x,s1,label='s1')

lg = ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05), ncol=10)

fig.savefig('A_test_position.png', facecolor='white', dpi = 300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

When I only keep the first 3 `ax.plot()` statements, I get [image: this]. However, when I include all the `ax.plot()` statements, the output becomes [image: this]

**Problem:**
I need to get the legend box to:

1. start at 0 on the x-axis
2. end at the maximum x-value on the x-axis (in this case, the max value would be 35)
3. wrap to a new row after it reaches the maximum on the x-axis

When there are a small number of entries (eg. first plot), then I want the legend to be centered. Currently my code is working correctly for this, so I do not need to change this behavior. However, I need to change the behavior when there are so many entries that the legend needs to wrap around to a new row (2nd plot).

How can this be done in Matplotlib? Is there a way to specify the size of the legend box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution would be to iterate over the `ncol` argument until the width of the legend becomes larger than the width of the axe. Then, make the legend to expand the entire width of the axe using the optimal value found for `ncol` and the `mode='expand'` option. In the case all the entries can fit in a single row, your "centered layout" is kept, without expanding the legend to the width of the axe.

Below is a code sample that shows how this can be done:

```
ncol = 1
lgwidth_old = 0.
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
while True:
    lg = ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0., -0.05, 1., 0.),
                   borderaxespad=0, ncol=ncol)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    lgbbox = lg.get_window_extent(renderer).inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)

    if lgwidth_old == lgbbox.width:
        # All the entries fit within a single row. Keep the legend
        # as is and break the loop.
        break

    if lgbbox.width < 1:
        # The width of the legend is still smaller than that of the axe.
        # Continue iterating.
        ncol += 1
        lgwidth_old = lgbbox.width
    else: 
        # The width of the legend is larger than that of the axe.
        # Backtrack ncol, plot the legend so it span the entire width of
        # the axe, and break the loop.
        ncol -= 1
        lg = ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0., -0.05, 1., 0.),
                       borderaxespad=0, ncol=ncol, mode='expand')         
        break

    if ncol > 100:
        print('Number max of iteration reached. Something is wrong.')
        break
```

which results in (when added to your code):

[image]

Comment: This works. However, I do not understand why the while loop is there. Could it be possible to say instead: `for ncol in range(1,100):`?

Comment: @WR Yes, you can do this with a `for` loop if you prefer this coding style. Should yield to the same result. I just prefer to use a `while` loop for these kind of problems for which the number of iterations is undetermined at the start.

Comment: What will determine the number of iterations? For example, I have 13 symbols in the plot. Would that mean `for ncol in range(1,13):`?

Comment: We can't determine the number of iteration in advance, otherwise there would be no need to iterate over `ncol`. The end of the loop is controlled with condional `break`. In the example you gave in the comment above, 13 would be the maximum possible number of iteration. But I do not understand what you would gain by doing that. You will have to explicitly specify the number of entry in your legend each time. Better to use a `while` loop or a `for` loop with a large range and let the conditional `break` do their job to end the loop imo.